# strftime() replace %OB for windows

Tags: windows, strtotime

Here is my code:

`strftime('%OB %Y', time());`

This line return false. How do I get this line for windows?

Thanks!

Comment: This code would not compile since it is missing parameters. Always show **real** code.

Answer (score 0):

If you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx), `%B` does not allow a prefix, so drop the `O`:

```
'%B %Y'
```